# VM14:102 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError

Tags: javascript, html

**VM14:102 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'predict' of undefined
at predict (VM14:102)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM17:73)**

This is the problematic part of the html.

Start
Predict

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // More API functions here:
    // https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachablemachine-community/tree/master/libraries/image

    // the link to your model provided by Teachable Machine export panel
    const URL = "./my_model/";

    let model, labelContainer, maxPredictions;

    async function init() {
        const modelURL = URL + "model.json";
        const metadataURL = URL + "metadata.json";

        // load the model and metadata
        // Refer to tmImage.loadFromFiles() in the API to support files from a file picker
        // or files from your local hard drive
        // Note: the pose library adds "tmImage" object to your window (window.tmImage)
        model = await tmImage.load(modelURL, metadataURL);
        maxPredictions = model.getTotalClasses();
        labelContainer = document.getElementById("label-container");
        for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) { // and class labels
            labelContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
        }
    }
    async function predict() {
        // predict can take in an image, video or canvas html element
        var image = document.getElementById("face-image");
        const prediction = await model.predict(image, false);
        for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) {
            const classPrediction =
                prediction[i].className + ": " + prediction[i].probability.toFixed(2);
            labelContainer.childNodes[i].innerHTML = classPrediction;
        }
    }
</script>
```

The error code is
VM14:102 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'predict' of undefined
at predict (VM14:102)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM17:73)

It comes out like this, but I can't fix it.
If you have the necessary data to fix the error, you can provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `model` variable isn't being initialized before you try to access `model.predict()`.

Make sure you're running `init()` on page load. Simply adding `init()` to the end of your `<script>` block should do the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // More API functions here:
    // https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachablemachine-community/tree/master/libraries/image

    // the link to your model provided by Teachable Machine export panel
    const URL = "./my_model/";

    let model, labelContainer, maxPredictions;

    async function init() {
        const modelURL = URL + "model.json";
        const metadataURL = URL + "metadata.json";

        // load the model and metadata
        // Refer to tmImage.loadFromFiles() in the API to support files from a file picker
        // or files from your local hard drive
        // Note: the pose library adds "tmImage" object to your window (window.tmImage)
        model = await tmImage.load(modelURL, metadataURL);
        maxPredictions = model.getTotalClasses();
        labelContainer = document.getElementById("label-container");
        for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) { // and class labels
            labelContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
        }
    }
    async function predict() {
        // predict can take in an image, video or canvas html element
        var image = document.getElementById("face-image");
        const prediction = await model.predict(image, false);
        for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) {
            const classPrediction =
                prediction[i].className + ": " + prediction[i].probability.toFixed(2);
            labelContainer.childNodes[i].innerHTML = classPrediction;
        }
    }
init(); // ⭐️
</script>
```

Comment: I added init(); but nothing changed the error.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'predict' of undefined
    at predict(VM17:103)

               labelContainer.childNodes[i].innerHTML = classPrediction;
            }
        }
(area is empty) <- this
This is where the error is indicated.
However, the display area is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the await model between () in the function predict as I show in line below.

const prediction = (await model).predict(image, false);

model is a Promise you need to await before you can access the properties of the object.

Comment: at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM17:73)
Solved but Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property'predict' of undefined
    at predict (VM17:101) is not resolved.